What is this IC marked "412"?
What is this IC marked "412"?


Can you put a bigger picture as well to show the surrounding components? Also give more information about the circuit e.g. what equipment that the circuit belongs to.

FWIW the device logo is from Siliconix (now Vishay)

Might be DG412 analog switch.

It's a Vishay DG412DQ SPST analog switch.

(Source: vishay.com)
I can't find a picture for the DG412, but here is one of the DG411DQ from lcsc.com that shows similar markings just with a 411 instead of 412.


+1 For a good answer. But just a side note: This appears to be a standardized part because there are multiple suppliers, like Analog Devices and Renesas, that also supply this chip.
